# Angular 2 selectBox value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can I display selected value from `selectBox`. I can't use the `ngModel` binding property because the number of selectBoxes is dynamically changing.
For example, I will have 50 rooms so I need 50 variables for every `selectBox`. Is there any other way to do it, or I have to use an array of selected values? This is my current code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let room of term.rooms">
    <th>{{room.name}}</th>
    <th><select #box><option *ngFor="let price of  getPrices(room.id)" [ngValue]="price">{{price.name}}</option></select></th>
    <th><!--ValueHere--></th><!--for example something like this price.value-->
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, you will need an array with 50 variables.

In your template, use `ngFor` to loop through your array and for each variable, create a dropdown and  use `[(ngModel)]` to bind data.

Let me know if you still couldn't figure out.